# How to sum values of objects and push it in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have an array of objects which is dynamic and depend on the selection of rows of a table. An example of it:

```
var obj = [
            { name: "test1",  totalCosts: 45560, actualTotalCosts: 652112, riskCosts: 65442 },
            { name: "test2",  totalCosts: 3434,  actualTotalCosts: 25252,   riskCosts: 34234 },
            { name: "test3",  totalCosts: 23123, actualTotalCosts: 23242,  riskCosts: 0 },
        ];
```

After this array is generated I want to call a function which pushes one more row in this array and names it "total" and sums all the respected values which would look like this:

> {name: "total", totalCosts:72117, actualTotalCosts:700606 , risksCosts: 99676 }
>
> obj[0].totalCosts + obj[1].totalCosts + obj[2].totalCosts = obj[3].totalCosts

I tried writing one with my limited knowledge, but that function instead of summing up the values from all three objects, summed up the entire object into one.

```
            function sum1( obj ) {
            var result1 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                var sum = 0, arr = [];
                for (var key in obj[i]) {
                    if (key != 'name') {
                        sum += obj[i][key];
                        arr.push(sum[key]);
                    }

                }
                result1.push(arr);
                return result1;
            }
        }
```

Please provide a function which can sum all the objects and return the array with the totals. I also tried using d3.sum but was not successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a functional approach with the aid of d3.sum...

```
  obj.push(d3.keys(obj[0])                //get the keys from obj[0]
    .reduce(function(sumRow, sumCol) {    //construct a summary row
      var isNum = !isNaN(obj[0][sumCol])  //only sum numeric fields
      return (sumRow[sumCol] = (isNum ? d3.sum(obj, function(row) {
        return row[sumCol]                //accessor for the column for  d3.sum
      }) : "All"), sumRow)                //append the sum col to the sum row object
    },{}));                               //initial value for reduce is {}
```

---

### Working example

```js
  (function() {
    var obj = [{
      name: "test1",
      name2: "type1",
      totalCosts: 45560,
      actualTotalCosts: 652112,
      riskCosts: 65442
    }, {
      name: "test2",
      name2: "type2",
      totalCosts: 3434,
      actualTotalCosts: 25252,
      riskCosts: 34234
    }, {
      name: "test3",
      name2: "type3",
      totalCosts: 23123,
      actualTotalCosts: 23242,
      riskCosts: 0
    }];

    obj.push(d3.keys(obj[0])
      .reduce(function(sumRow, sumCol) {
        var isNum = !isNaN(obj[0][sumCol])
        return (sumRow[sumCol] = (isNum ? d3.sum(obj, function(row) {
          return row[sumCol]
        }) : "All"), sumRow)
      }, {}));

    d3.select("#result").text(JSON.stringify(obj))
  })()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Nice answer! You might want to change the column's name from "All" to "total" to fully match OP's requirements.

Comment: @altocumulus cheers mate... yes, maybe you're right. I did consider that but selected "All" because I'm working on generalising it into an object with arbitrary summarising operation and exclusion rule.

Comment: Worked for me , thanks perfect answer, I already have d3 in my page as its a angular d3 application

Comment: Ok, good. To me it's just another example that shows that it's rare that you can't find the code you need already existing in d3. It's always worth looking arround; and the ECMA5 functional programming style is a powerful tool to enable that.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: It's important to realize that what you are calling `var obj` is actually an array.

That being said, you can iterate over your array and do this:

```
function sumAll(arr) {

  // Create variables for the costs we're tracking
  var totalCosts = 0;
  var actualTotalCosts = 0;
  var riskCosts = 0;

  arr.forEach(function(elem) {
    // At each iteration of our loop, increase the appropriate variables by their appropriate values
    if (elem.hasOwnProperty('totalCosts')) {
      totalCosts += elem.totalCosts;
    }
    if (elem.hasOwnProperty('actualTotalCosts')) {
    actualTotalCosts += elem.actualTotalCosts;
    }
    if (elem.hasOwnProperty('riskCosts')) {
      riskCosts += elem.riskCosts
    }
  });

  // Return an object with the information we'd like to have
  return {
    name: 'total',
    totalCosts: totalCosts,
    actualTotalCosts: actualTotalCosts,
    riskCosts: riskCosts
  }
}
```

From your code:

```
var obj = [
            { name: "test1",  totalCosts: 45560, actualTotalCosts: 652112, riskCosts: 65442 },
            { name: "test2",  totalCosts: 3434,  actualTotalCosts: 25252,   riskCosts: 34234 },
            { name: "test3",  totalCosts: 23123, actualTotalCosts: 23242,  riskCosts: 0 },
        ];
```

Calling my function:

```
sumAll(obj) // {name: "total", totalCosts: 72117, actualTotalCosts: 700606, riskCosts: 99676}
```

Comment: Don't you need to use Objects hasOwnProperty, within the foreach loop? I know it's an array you're looping through, but you're checking the Obects properties?

Comment: You're right, I should have a check there for edge cases. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty()` should take a string, not a variable `totalCosts` which is absolutely a number.

Comment: Won't work, totalCosts, actualCosts are dynamic and can change anytime a user selects  different costs values.